# go mongo error: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'ready.$cond' is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to update my collection using go-mongo driver [findOneAndUpdate](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.FindOneAndUpdate) method.

I am trying to `$set` the `ready` field like this

```
    if update, ok := update["$set"].(bson.M); ok {
        setter["ready"] = getModifier()
    }
```

My `getModifier()` looks like this.

```
func getModifier() bson.M {
    andQuery := []bson.M{{
        "$ne": bson.A{"$catalog_field", nil},
    }}

    andQuery = append(andQuery, bson.M{"$ne": bson.A{"$pricing_field", nil}})

    query := bson.M{
        "$cond": bson.M{  //this is where the error is happening, read further
            "if": bson.M{
                "$and": andQuery,
            },
            "then": true,
            "else": false,
        },
    }

    return query
}
```

And then I pass the new `update` to the mongo driver like this, along with other params.

`result := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, filter, update, opts)`

When I run this, I get an error saying

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'ready.$cond' is not valid for storage
```

Why is `$cond` not valid here?.What am I missing?.

Comment: Could you attach the full code?